# Page layout got messed up

Tags: mysql, html, css

I have a lot of web pages that use the same exact html structure.

For some reason the width on this [page](http://bit.ly/MvxEY7) got messed up. This is what the layout supposed to look like http://bit.ly/Ie7yZ4 .

The only difference on these pages is the text content wich is delivered from MySQL database.

I think the problem has something to do with first few paragraphs on page, but I cannot figure out what it is.

P.S: Please, if you do not know how to fix the problem, yet want to educate me about table-less layouts and divs, please save your breath - I had my reasons to go with tables, and all of the pages rank very high in google, load fast and easy to maintain.

Comment: _"easy to maintain"_ - ummm...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last span "Search tags" has several very long sentences without any spaces. These lines force the layout width.
For example:
`08601,08602,08603,08604,08605,08606,08607,08608,08609,08610,08611,08618,08619,08620,08625,08628,08629,08638,08641,08645,08646,08647,08648,08650,08666,08690,08691,08695,`

I would recommend to add spaces between those words so it can be displayed on multiple lines or put them in a scrolled container with max width.

Comment: Ahh, you my hero! For some reason after I did last mysql export/import it erased all the spaces after the commas.

Answer (score 3):

the reason is in `Search tags` section on the bottom of the page. There is long text without any spaces which stretchs table cell.

add spaces or as an option add to `span` tag style properties

```
width: 600px;
display: block;
word-wrap: break-word;
```

Comment: this is a very elegant elegant css solution , I would credit you with answer, however mazzucci was first to point the problem out. I would have to go with adding spaces since this way it will make it look like a single block of text

Answer (score 2):

It's because of the **Search tags** which are very long.

You can change it with a bit of css though:

```
width: 615px;
display: block;
word-wrap: break-word;
```

Add that to the span that holds the tags and you should be good.
This Wraps the tags inside the container.

Or add spaces after each comma of course.

Answer (score 0):

It's that hideously long alt tag you've got on the containing `<p>` for that paragraph:

> alt="Mold Testing Trenton, Mercer County NJ New Jersey08601 ,08602,08603,08604,08605,08606,08607,08608,08609,08610,08611,08618,08619,08620,08625,08628,08629,08638,08641,08645,08646,08647,08648,08650,08666,08690,08691,08695,"

removing that fixes the paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem with the search tags you've included in the span at the end of the paragraph, if you really need them (personally I'd use `display: none`, or remove them altogether)) then you'll need to apply `table-layout: fixed;` to the table, and `word-wrap: break-word;` to the span.